# makefile, what is the best way to design the build in several subdirectories

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a project which include c++ and java code, 
the structure now looks like:

```
  dev -- |--- display1 (sub makefile:needs compile both c++ and java)
         |--- display2 
         |--- ddv      (sub makefile: needs compile both c++ and java)
         |--- def
         |--- Install  (makefile: call sub makefiles in the other 4 folders)
```

I wonder if they are other better ways to deal with this case. 
For example, if there are ways to generate a makefile with source in subdirectories , using just one makefile for this case. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

I am new to makefile, hope to get good advices here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Make, you should start with simple tasks and work up to complex ones.

Suppose you have `display1/disp1.cc` and want to build `display1/disp1.o`. You can do that with a rule in `Install/Makefile`:

```
display1/disp1.o: display1/disp1.cc
    g++ -c display1/disp1.cc -o display1/disp1.o
```

**Get that working perfectly before you proceed.** Then you can have several such rules in `Install/Makefile`:

```
display1/disp1.o: display1/disp1.cc
    g++ -c display1/disp1.cc -o display1/disp1.o

display1/foo1.o: display1/foo1.cc
    g++ -c display1/foo1.cc -o display1/foo1.o

display1/foo2.o: display1/foo2.cc
    g++ -c display1/foo2.cc -o display1/foo2.o
```

Then you can use automatic variables to make the rules cleaner:

```
display1/disp1.o: display1/disp1.cc
    g++ -c $< -o $@

display1/foo1.o: display1/foo1.cc
    g++ -c $< -o $@

display1/foo2.o: display1/foo2.cc
    g++ -c $< -o $@
```

**Get that working perfectly before you proceed.** Then you can replace all those rules with a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro):

```
display1/%.o: display1/%.cc
    g++ -c $< -o $@
```

**Get that working... well, you get the idea.** Then you can write more pattern rules for the other directories:

```
display1/%.o: display1/%.cc
    g++ -c $< -o $@

display2/%.o: display2/%.cc
    g++ -c $< -o $@

ddv/%.o: ddv/%.cc
    g++ -c $< -o $@

def/%.o: def/%.cc
    g++ -c $< -o $@
```

Then four more pattern rules to cover the java (which I could attempt, but I'm not a javanaut.)

Then you can write lists of targets and keep them in their respective directories, and use the `include` directive to pull them into `Install/Makefile`.

There's more you can do, but that much should keep you busy for a while. Let us know if you run into trouble.